# Create a dynamic function

Tags: go

There is an existing logic I need to achieve in Golang. In general it is something like:

```
// Function receives an object with a variable type (struct)
func(dynObject interface{}) {

    var variableFunc ... // What should be here?

    // Some things to do depending on the input param type
    switch dynObject.(type) {
    case *objA:
        // do some job
    case *objB:
        // do some job
    }

    // ...
    // Creating and calculating some variables for the following loop
    // ...

    humans := []*Humans{ ....... }
    sum := []int{}

    for _, human := range humans {
        result := variableFunc(dynObject, human)
        sum = append(sum, result)
    }
}
```

As you see - as an input there is a **dynObject** which is a struct, but can be any of some predefined structs. Later there is a function `variableFunc` which must take this object and process, and processing logic also depends on the type. So type **objA** requires different logic than **objB**.

I don't know a normal way to implement this. How do I create this dynamic function, which can take different structs as input and apply needed logic to it? At the moment I get an error, that function expects another type as an input. And I wish to avoid additional switch-case, because one already exists.

Of course I tried to create a predefined func., and with interfaces, then somehow redefine it inside of existing switch-case, but no luck. I need your help

Comment: so far, you are on the track to creating a function which will accept an interface, and switch code based on type. You shouldn't be getting any error of the type, "At the moment I get an error, that function expects another type as an input", can you copy paste the error you are getting here?

Comment: If variableFunc is dynamic, maybe it would help to see its pseudo-code or its logic ? Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean to achieve.

Comment: @vdolez, I believe it doesn't really matter in this case, just imagine they are different. Like objA needs `objA.x+objA.y`, but objB needs `objB.z * 150 - objB.n`

Comment: @whitespace, if I put interfaces everywhere - I'll need additional switch-case inside of `variableFunc` - I wish to avoid it, as one already exists

Comment: can't you pass the variableFunc as a an additional parameter of the encapsulating function ? it seems to me this functions are already defined somewhere (maybe in a DB ?) and not so _dynamic_

Comment: @vdolez, true, logics are static and known, but dynamic is `variableFunc` which applies needed logic. How do I pass a function which can also be changed? Again `if .. else ..` inside a loop?

Comment: @Alexey, why? if variableFunc is a function which is meant to handle a specific type, it can be done by type-asserting the interface https://tour.golang.org/methods/15. On the other hand if you are creating a multi interface variable type function inside another dynamic function, you will indeed end up using more switch statements. So the question here, is the encapsulating function and the variableFunc both meant to be "dynamic", or is the encapsulating function "static", while variableFunc is "dynamic"?

Comment: @whitespace, every struct requires specific existing and predefined logic/function - it is known. I don't know how to call needed function depending on the **dynObject** type, without additional switch-case

Comment: @Alexey, I may be wrong but I think "Of course I tried to create a predefined func., and with interfaces then somehow redefine it inside of existing switch-case"  is the easiest approach. If you tried creating the functions using interface type, it would not work, that might be your issue.

Comment: @whitespace, for example, I tried predefining like this: `var variableFunc func(interface{}, *Human) int` - it doesn't work, as I can't put another function atop of it later. Can you show a working example?

Comment: Couldn't you just add 2 functions to each of the structs (like `DoWork()` and `HandleHuman(*Human) int`) which implement the struct-specific logic? Then you could also create an interface, which contains these functions and your base function can take an argument of that interface type. Then all you have to do is call the 2 functions. This approach also gets rid of the first switch, as you only have to call the `DoWork()` function.

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem. You probably don't actually need a dynamic function, but are too focused on your imagined solution to see the bigger picture. Can you explain the larger problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    common(4)
    common("whitespace")
}
func common(a interface{}) {
    switch a.(type) {
    case int:
        div(a.(int), 2)
        break
    case string:
        sayHello(a.(string))
        break
    default:
        //nothing
    }
    return
}
func div(a, b int) {
    fmt.Printf("%d", a/b)
    return
}
func sayHello(a string) {
    fmt.Printf("%s", a)
}
```

`main` function calls a `common` function, this in turn calls two different functions, which have different function signatures. You can see that they perform different actions. So this will print different results for different inputs. If calling different functions inside your switch statement is what you, wanted to do(as much I can glean from your comments), then this should do it. Let me know.

---

> there is a job to do inside my switch-case, then it's result is being used to calculate other variables (middle section in my example), and only after that I call variableFunc()

```
package stackoverflow

import "fmt"

func common(a interface{}) {
    switch a.(type) {
    case int:
        defer func(b int) {
            fmt.Printf("%d \n", b/2)
        }(a.(int))
        break
    case string:
        defer func(b string) {
            fmt.Printf("hello %s \n", b)
        }(a.(string))
        break
    default:
        //nothing
    }

    //do something here
    fmt.Println("did something here test")
    // the function gets called after
    return
}
```

you can use defer. So, this isn't a conventional use of defer. But technically it can be used for something like this. The above functionality will execute only after `//something` gets done, which I believe is the kind of flexibility you are after. If some function panics, this statement will come in between execution and exiting. So, you have to know what you are doing.

---

Or you can use this, in case you have parameters coming in at a later stage.

```
package stackoverflow

import "fmt"

func common(a interface{}) {
    var f func(interface{}, int)
    switch a.(type) {
    case int:
        f = func(s interface{}, b int) {
            fmt.Printf("%d and %d\n", s.(int)/2, b)
        }
        break
    case string:
        f = func(b interface{}, c int) {
            fmt.Printf("hello %s and %d \n", b.(string), c)
        }
        break
    default:
        //nothing
    }
    //do something here
    fmt.Println("did something here test")
    // the function gets called after
    var x int = 21

    f(a, x)

    return
}
```

Comment: Close. But you skip some things: there is a job to do inside my switch-case, then it's result is being used to calculate other variables (middle section in my example), and only after that I call `variableFunc()`. In your example I can't call `div()` or `sayHello()` so soon because not all needed parameters are known yet. In my case it's like switch-case after switch-case where I wish to avoid the second switch at least.